# Accessing elements of a ruby data structure

Tags: ruby, hash

I've got a ruby data structure that looks like this:

```
my_item
=> {:data_id=>"some id",
 :description=>
  "some description",
 :time=>"some time",
 :name=>"some name"}
```

I assume it's a hash but if I try and access the data I get `nil` back. e.g.:

```
puts my_item['name']

=> nil
```

How do you access the elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Strings](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html) and [symbols](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Symbol.html) aren't the same thing. If you use a symbol (`:name`) as an index, you can't access it with a string:

```
foo = { :name => 'Hello' }
puts foo[:name]  # => "Hello"
puts foo['name']  # => nil
```

Likewise, you can't use a symbol to access an element if a string (`'name'`) is used:

```
bar = { 'name' => 'World' }
puts bar[:name]  # => nil
puts bar['name']  # => "World"
```

Note that [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org) *does* allow strings and symbols to be interchanged to some degree - see the [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`my_item` is a Hash, whose keys are all symbols (e.g, `:name`), while you are using a string (`'name'`) as the key.

```
my_item[:name]
# => "some name"
```